# What's the exact process for dealing with off topic posts?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

I asked a question on main about mathematical interestingness of statements with the intent of finding a heuristic or formal theory that attempts to define mathematical interestingness. I included one tag as obviously wrong in hindsight, set theory, because I intended to ask about the interestingness or utility of first order statements with foundations in set theory before realizing any foundation would be appropriate.

The damage was done, and someone removed all the tags I assumed were relevant and retagged it as soft-question and philosophy. Shortly after that it acquired a close vote and after several hours it acquired enough close votes to be put on hold.

Now I don't want to contribute useless or off topic questions that aren't useful to the community, and I'm wonder where I go from here? Do I delete the post, even though there were helpful answers linked in comments? Does it get migrated to another SE site? Do I just wait?

I'm not sure I can edit it meaningfully enough to satisfy those who voted to close it and still have it be the same question. I could edit it to be higher quality and more rigorous, but the question would still be in the realm of asking how or if we can measure mathematical depth in first order statements, so if that question is off topic I can't really fix the question.

Is it appropriate to ask in the comments in main the reasoning behind the close vote and possible alternative SE sites, or should the comments avoid meta questions like that?

[Is there any formal definition or reasonably good heuristic for mathematical 'interestingness?'](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/828557/is-there-any-formal-definition-or-reasonably-good-heuristic-for-mathematical-in)

Comment: I removed the tags, but I didn't vote or flag the post (for what it's worth, I don't recall flagging any question as low quality in the past three years or so. Instead I vote to close).

Comment: Your edit (as your original) somehow implies that I initiated the closure process. Do you see my name in the list of people who voted to close? I removed the tags because your question didn't have much to do with set theory. In either case these edits are not etched in stone, and if you disagreed you could have put [at least some of] the tags back on the question.

Comment: Changed to voted to close, didn't mean to imply flag. I still don't know what to do with the question though. Am I supposed to delete it or do I wait for the community to do it? I'm not sure what SE site would be more appropriate. I don't think its a bad question, and I think its about mathematics, but if the community feels otherwise I'd like to know what to do with it.

Comment: I couldn't see names of close voters until it was on hold, so I just assumed it was the same person; I edited to differentiate, apologies. I wanted to ask about the process in general rather than your specific interaction with it. I didn't really want to put tags back that a high rep user removed, since I don't want to be involved in any sort of edit war about a question I was just curious about, and I don't quite know how such disagreements are resolved.